# Can we pass nullable Argument in room query

Tags: android, database, android-room

Here is my query

I am trying to search property by given params
if the given param is null then it should take all properties and don't filter

```
@Query("""SELECT * FROM Property 
    WHERE 
    (listedFor = :lookingTo OR :lookingTo IS NULL) AND
    (propertyType IN (:propertyType) OR :propertyType IS NULL) AND
    (areaId IN(:areasOfProperties) OR :areasOfProperties IS NULL) AND
    cityId = :cityId
    ORDER BY registrationDate DESC""")
fun getPropertyListBySearchQuery(
    lookingTo: String?,
    propertyType: ArrayList<String>?,
    areasOfProperties: ArrayList<String>?,
    cityId: String,
) : LiveData<List<Property>>
```

This is giving me crash as below

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.
        at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:92)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Property 
            WHERE 
            (listedFor = ? OR ? IS NULL) AND
            (propertyType IN (?,?) OR ?,? IS NULL) AND
            (areaId IN() OR  IS NULL) AND
            cityId = ?
            ORDER BY registrationDate DESC
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:965)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:576)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1353)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1328)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.query(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:183)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:530)
        at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.java:86)
        at com.townproperties.data.localdata.LocalDao_Impl$23.call(LocalDao_Impl.java:1515)
        at com.townproperties.data.localdata.LocalDao_Impl$23.call(LocalDao_Impl.java:1512)
        at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:90)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Can we pass nullable Argument in room query?***

Yes but it's a little convoluted.

**Brief Explanation**

The issue that you have shown is not an issue with whether or not one of the args is NULL (in which case I believe you would encounter an NPE (null pointer exception)) **but** that you are trying to check a list (CSV) as if it were a single value and thus the comma results in the syntax error.

- the **`?`*'s indicate to SQLite that the value will be a bound value - see https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html

A way around this would be to build the SQL and use an `@RawQuery`. the SQL being built in a function with a body. The following is a working demonstration:-

First the `@Dao` annotated interface :-

```
@Dao
interface PropertyDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(property: Property)
    
    @RawQuery
    fun rawQueryPropertyList(rawQuery: SimpleSQLiteQuery): List<Property>

    fun getPropertiesBySearchCriteria(
        lookingTo: String?,
        propertyType: ArrayList<String>?,
        areasOfProperties: ArrayList<String>?,
        cityId: String
    ): List<Property> {
        var afterFirstInList: Boolean = false
        var whereAdded = false
        val baseSQL = "SELECT * FROM Property"
        val qry: StringBuilder = java.lang.StringBuilder().append(baseSQL)
        /* Looking To */
        if (lookingTo != null && lookingTo.length > 0) {
            if (!whereAdded) {
                qry.append(" WHERE ")
                whereAdded = true
            }
            if (qry.length > baseSQL.length)  qry.append(" AND ")
            qry.append(" listedFor='${lookingTo}'")
        }
        /* Property Type */
        if (propertyType!= null && propertyType.size > 0) {
            afterFirstInList = false
            if (qry.length > baseSQL.length) qry.append(" AND ")
            if (!whereAdded) {
                qry.append(" WHERE ")
                whereAdded = true
            }
            qry.append(" propertyType IN (")
            for (s in propertyType) {
                if (afterFirstInList) qry.append(",")
                qry.append("'${s}'")
                afterFirstInList = true
            }
            qry.append(")")
        }
        if (areasOfProperties!=null && areasOfProperties?.size!! > 0) {
            afterFirstInList = false
            if (qry.length > baseSQL.length) qry.append(" AND ")
            if (!whereAdded) {
                qry.append(" WHERE ")
                whereAdded = true
            }
            qry.append(" areaId IN (")
            for (s in areasOfProperties) {
                if (afterFirstInList) qry.append(",")
                qry.append("'${s}'")
                afterFirstInList = true
            }
            qry.append(")")
        }
        if (qry.length > baseSQL.length) qry.append(" AND ")
        if (!whereAdded) {
            qry.append(" WHERE ")
            whereAdded = true
        }
        qry.append(" cityId='${cityId}' ")
        qry.append(" ORDER BY registrationDate DESC")
        Log.d("PRPRTYINFO_SQL",qry.toString()) /* ONLY FOR TESTING */
        return rawQueryPropertyList(SimpleSQLiteQuery(qry.toString()))
    }
}
```

The '@Entity' annotated **Property** data class used to test (obviously probably not what you have, but built according to what is available from the question). *differences would probably not matter that much if at all*:

```
@Entity
data class Property(
    @PrimaryKey
    var propertyId: Long?=null,
    var propertyType: String,
    var areaId: Long,
    var cityId: Long,
    var listedFor: Long,
    var registrationDate: Long
)
```

A pretty standard `@Database` annotated class was used. Note that for brevity and convenience `.allowMainThreadQueries` was used.

Finally the activity code used to perform the limited testing:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: PropertyDatabase
    lateinit var dao: PropertyDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = PropertyDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getPropertyDao()

        dao.insert(Property(null,"House",100,1090,100,System.currentTimeMillis() ))
        dao.insert(Property(null,"Flat",200,2090,200,System.currentTimeMillis()))
        dao.insert(Property(null,"Villa",300,3090,300,System.currentTimeMillis()))


        logProperties(dao.getPropertiesBySearchCriteria("", arrayListOf(""), arrayListOf(""),"1090"),"T1")
        logProperties(
            dao.getPropertiesBySearchCriteria(
                lookingTo = "",
                propertyType =  arrayListOf("House","Flat","Villa","Apartment","Castle"),
                areasOfProperties =  arrayListOf("1","2","100","200","300","1000000000"),
                cityId = "1090"
            ),
            "T2"
        )
        logProperties(dao.getPropertiesBySearchCriteria(null, null, null,"1090"),"T3")
    }


    fun logProperties(plist: List<Property>, tagSuffix: String ) {
        val TAG = "PRPRTYINFO_${tagSuffix}"
        for (p in plist) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Type=${p.propertyType} AreaId=${p.areaId} CityId=${p.cityId} ListedFor=${p.listedFor} RDate=${Date(p.registrationDate)}")
        }
    }
}
```

When run for a fresh install (only deigned to run the once) then the Log includes:-

```
2022-09-26 12:35:46.722 D/PRPRTYINFO_SQL: SELECT * FROM Property WHERE  propertyType IN ('') AND  areaId IN ('') AND  cityId='1090'  ORDER BY registrationDate DESC

2022-09-26 12:35:46.728 D/PRPRTYINFO_SQL: SELECT * FROM Property WHERE  propertyType IN ('House','Flat','Villa','Apartment','Castle') AND  areaId IN ('1','2','100','200','300','1000000000') AND  cityId='1090'  ORDER BY registrationDate DESC
2022-09-26 12:35:46.741 D/PRPRTYINFO_T2: Type=House AreaId=100 CityId=1090 ListedFor=100 RDate=Mon Sep 26 12:35:46 GMT+10:00 2022

2022-09-26 12:35:46.741 D/PRPRTYINFO_SQL: SELECT * FROM Property WHERE  cityId='1090'  ORDER BY registrationDate DESC
2022-09-26 12:35:46.742 D/PRPRTYINFO_T3: Type=House AreaId=100 CityId=1090 ListedFor=100 RDate=Mon Sep 26 12:35:46 GMT+10:00 2022
```

- each of the 3 invocations write the generated SQL to the log.
- The first invocation selects nothing as none have empty strings in the propertyType and areaId (so don't use empty strings UNLESS you expect empty strings)
- The second, due to the cityId being required gets just the one property (otherwise it would get all 3 properties)
- Likewise the 3rd will get all properties (nulls for the nullables) but for the cityId being required.

An alternative that wouldn't require building the SQL at run time and using a rawquery (unchecked at compile time, although as per your example the compile time check isn't 100% anyway), would be to utilise CTE (Common Table expressions (temporary tables within the query)). However this could well be more complex than building the SQL due to having to manage the lists as well as the lack of the lists.

Comment: good explanation. currently, i have managed this in a repository with a different types of queries by manually checking of data exist or not